# Unable to split an objects properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to wrap an svg label by wrapping the string in tspan tags.

My problem is that the property isn't working when split() occurs. My object doesn't seem to work inside the function, however it seems to work in console. d.text returns in console but as far as working inside the function, something is off.

```
 function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function (d) {

            console.log("is d.text defined?"  + d.text /* this gets returned ok - logs all the d.text*/)
            wordwrap = ( function (){return "These are long labels" /*hardcoded label strings: this gets returned ok*/})
            wordwrap = ( function (){return d.text; /* undefined is not a function */})
            wordwrap = d.text; /* number is not a function */


            var text = d3.select(this),
                words = wordwrap().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                lineNumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                x = text.attr("x"),
                y = text.attr("y"),
                dy = 0, //parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                tspan = text.text(null)
                    .append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dy", dy + "em");
            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan")
                        .attr("x", x)
                        .attr("y", y)
                        .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                        .text(word);
                }

                console.log(d.text) /* this gets returned ok*/
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your function isn't doing anything. .each isn't a native JavaScript function. Is this supposed to be jQuery? You would use $.each( array, function( ix, text ){}); where array is an array of strings.